# Property of a supremum of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that if the Measure Space is Finite ($\mu(X)<\infty)$, then $\lim\sup \mu(A_n)\le \mu(\lim\sup A_n)$ Where $\lim\sup A_n=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

I understand the solution, what I don't get is why do we have to demand the space to be finite? Yet we don't demand that in the similar equation for the infimum: $\mu(\lim\inf A_n)\le \lim\inf\mu(A_n)$ Where $\lim\inf A_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

For if $\mu(A_n)=\infty$ surely $\mu(\lim\sup A_n)=\infty$ right? so the equation will hold.

Thanks,

Comment: Try sets $[n,n+1)$ on the real line.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Why wouldn't there be such an example for the Infimum?

Comment: $\mu(A_n) = \infty$ will not imply that $\mu(\limsup A_n) = \infty$, since the limit superior consists of points that belong in infinitely many of the sets. In particular, since we can easily find infinitely many disjoint sets on the real line with infinite measure, the limit superior of such a sequence  will be the empty set. This cannot be done with a set of finite measure, since for every $\epsilon > 0$ you cannot have infinitely many disjoint sets of measure greater than $\epsilon$.

Comment: For the liminf case it "feels" like there shouldn't be a problem with infinite measures because the terms that could potentially go to infinity are on the greater side of the inequality. But of course proof and counterexample are the way to go.